Do you have to deploy Postgresql manually if you run Ansible Tower on OpenShift?
I'm looking at deploying Ansible Tower on OpenShift but don't want to deal with deploying my own Postgresql instance if I don't have to (not that it's a big deal).
If I deploy Ansible Tower on OpenShift, the diagram makes it look like I have to deploy my own instance of Postgresql instead of it using its normal embedded instance.
Is that accurate or will it spin up its own Postgresql pod?

Actually you can perform both. In my opinion if you're not into DB i'll say to keep the embbeded postgresql that works really well.
In another case, you can easily link an existing DB to your AWX/Tower instance deployment.
Documentation mentions both scenarios here :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/openshift_configuration.html#database-configuration-and-usage
First one is recommended but not mandatory. In my case I used embedded and never have any issues since 1,5 years.
(EDIT: i run my instance on a Nutanix Kubernetes Engine.)
